# Oracle Apex Regional Header

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Good afternoon,

I am trying to build a page using Oracle APEX 19.2.  I have the application built and working fine, but now I am trying to make some changes for ease of navigation and titles.

I am trying to create a region header that would reflect the current data shown on page 4 of my table.

On the page editor, in the Region panes, I go down to the Header and Footer area and am able to create the header text using html and css, but is there a way to create the title based on a column from page 4?

I have a column on page 4 that is titled PN.  Is there a way that I can take the text from Page 4_PN and make that the header for the region?

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to create the title based on a column from page 4?

Yes. Navigate to "Title" region's property and put (literally) `&PN.` in there - it'll take value from item named `PN` and use it as that region's title.